# Use streamfield in multiple apps: migration error

Tags: wagtail

My wagtail website project is split in different apps, like `core`, `event`, `publications` etc. and I set up my streamfield in `core.models`.

Now I would like to reuse this streamfield not only in `core.models`, but also in `event.models`.

But what's the most elegant (dry) way of defining my streamfield (subclassing `StreamBlock`) only once and reuse it in all my apps?

My `StreamBlock` is inspired by the one from the [wagtaildemo](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtaildemo/blob/master/demo/models.py#L71) project:

```
# core/models.py
class StoryBlock(StreamBlock):
    h2 = CharBlock(icon="title", classname="title")
    h3 = CharBlock(icon="title", classname="title")
    h4 = CharBlock(icon="title", classname="title")
    intro = RichTextBlock(icon="pilcrow")
    paragraph = RichTextBlock(icon="pilcrow")
    aligned_image = ImageBlock(label="Aligned image")
    pullquote = PullQuoteBlock()
    read_on = ReadOnBlock()
```

-

```
# event/models.py
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel
from core.models import StoryBlock

class EventIndexPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(StoryBlock())

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

But trying to `makemigrations` the updated `EventIndexPage` page model yields a warning that I am `trying to add a non-nullable field 'body' to eventindexpage without a default` - but this only happens with (stream-)fields on non-`core`-models.

Passing the requested default value - be it `"asdf"` or `"[]"` - to `makemigrations` build the migration file, but the following `migrate` fails:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
...
  File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/fields.py", line 90, in get_prep_value
    return json.dumps(self.stream_block.get_prep_value(value), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
  File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/stream_block.py", line 205, in get_prep_value
    for child in value  # child is a BoundBlock instance
  File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/stream_block.py", line 205, in <listcomp>
    for child in value  # child is a BoundBlock instance
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'block'
```

[Full traceback](http://dpaste.com/3Z25SXZ)

If this is connected with my issue: this project will be deployed to openshift, so I'm limited to Django 1.8 when using Python 3. And glad to use wagtail 1.5.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't `from core.models import DemoStreamBlock` in your non-core models.py files all you need?

Comment: That was my first try. But the migration for my updated `event.EventIndexPage` model is of the opinion, that my new (stream-)field `body` is non-nullable and I should define a default value. This happens **only** when trying to add this streamfield in non-`core`  models. I will try to be more specific in my question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the migration warning is unrelated to where the StreamBlock is defined - it will happen any time you try to add a non-nullable field on a table that already has data in it. I would suggest passing `"[]"` (including the quotes) when prompted for a default value.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I pass as a default value. The `makemigrations` will continue without errors and build the migration file. But the following `migrate` yields the next error (question updated).

Comment: Looks like `""` is the correct thing to use as the default - just tried this now, and it avoided the `'str' object has no attribute 'block'` error. Sorry for the misinformation!

Comment: Wow, thank you! No I'm able to migrate my updated model. But why did this streamfield / `streamblock` is not nullable, respectivly there seems to be no way to define it as `null=True, blank=True`? And sorry, I can't mark your comment as an answer...

Comment: Thanks a lot gasman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [gasman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1853523/gasman) pointeted out in in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601775/use-streamfield-in-multiple-apps?noredirect=1#comment62706287_37601775), using `""` as default value for the migration did the trick.